# segmentation fault (core dumped) error with multiple loops

Tags: c, loops, coredump

I'm making a sudoku solving program, but I got the segmentation fault (core dumped) error in the function below.
In this function, I'm trying to fill in -1 in the places that a specific number cannot be filled.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
void check(int mat[9][9])
{
  int i, j, k, m;
  int num = 1;
  int top, left;

  while (num < 10) {
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<9; j++) {
        if (mat[i][j] == num) {  

//--------- core dumped error occurs here-------------

          for (k=0; k<9; k++) {
            if (mat[i][k] == 0) mat[i][k] = -1;  // check row
            if (mat[k][j] == 0) mat[k][j] = -1;  // check column
          }

          top = (i/3)*3;
          left = (j/3)*3;
          for (k=0; k<3; k++) { 
            for (m=0; m<3; k++) { 
              if(mat[k+top][m+left] == 0) mat[k+top][m+left] = -1; // check square
            }
          } 

//------------------------------------------ 

        }
      }
    }

    // code abbreviation

    num++;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
      for (k=0; k<3; k++) { 
        for (m=0; m<3; k++) {
```

sure looks broken/suspicious to me. Note that both loops increment `k`, so the outer one will never iterate. The inner one will run forever, I think, and can certainly trigger invalid accesses due to reading all over memory.

Comment: Thanks! How careless I am! haha

Answer (score 0):

this line is the problem:

```
for (m=0; m<3; k++)  //<< notice incrementing 'k' rather than 'm'
```

it should be:

```
for (m=0; m<3; m++)
```